# London ULEZ charged automatically?

Tags: london, tolls

London has recently introduced the Ultra Low Emission Zone (ULEZ). High polluting vehicles will need to pay a daily charge of £12.50.

I know people who drive through this zone quite often and was wondering if there is a feature where it can charge them automatically?

Comment: In the comments to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/147383/102507) you claim to be a child. How can you be driving through the ULEZ?

Comment: @user102507 The OP doesn't say he's the driver.

Comment: @David he did in the version when that comment was written

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't see that. But even if the OP is a child, how does that make the question improper?

Comment: @David I agree, the question’s totally fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A feature is offered called autopay for a £10 admin fee per vehicle.

It is described on the [TFL website](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/auto-pay?intcmp=2154):

> ## Benefits of Auto Pay
>
> - A reduced daily Congestion Charge
> - Never forget to pay charges again
> - Protection from receiving Penalty Charge Notices while registered
> - Registration for up to five vehicles

This will make all charges be paid automatically and can be set up for up to five vehicles. To set it up for personal use, go to the TFL website [here](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/autopay-apply-before-you-begin).